# menu items disappear during vertical scrolling in html

Tags: html, css

Menu items disappear during vertical scrolling.

CSS

```
<div style="transition:transform 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1); left: 0px; top: 
        inherit; width: 80px; height: calc(100% - 88px); overflow: auto;position: fixed; z-index: 1300; ">
    <div>
        <span tabindex="0" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; transition:450ms
         cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1); border-image: none; text-align: center; 
         line-height: 48px; display: block; white-space: nowrap; position: relative; ">
            .. Home
        </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span tabindex="0" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; transition:450ms
         cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1); border-image: none; text-align: center; 
         line-height: 48px; display: block; white-space: nowrap; position: relative; ">
            .. About US
        </span>
    </div>
    ....
    ....
    ....    
</div>
```

For the parent div when `display: inline-table` is applied the infinite scroll stops but then vertical scrolling doesn't work when screen is resized. This issue occurs only in Internet Explorer

Comment: add your html code please

Comment: Please read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask And try to think how anyone will be able to help you if you have provided no working example, or even any code to review.

Comment: @MateuszJuruś I have updated the code

Comment: @Pogrindis quite difficult to replicate it with a working sample.. So just giving the code which is causing it.

Comment: If that is the code that's causing it, then simply delete the code. That's not how you ask a question. Again read here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Pogrindis ok i have updated the post